# wrong results from cusolverDnDDgels

Tags: c++, cuda, cusolver

I wanted to test the cuda implementation of xgels provided with CUDA 11.1, and it seems I cannot make it work properly.
For instance, this code seems to run just fine:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <cusolverDn.h>
int main()
{
    const int m = 1000;
    const int n = 10;
    const int nrhs = 2;

    arma::mat A(m, n, arma::fill::randn);
    arma::mat B(m, nrhs, arma::fill::randn);

    A.col(0).fill(1.0);
    B += 10.0;
    const arma::mat refX = arma::solve(A, B);
    
    cusolverDnHandle_t handle;
    cusolverDnCreate(&handle);
    cusolverStatus_t status;
    const int lda = m;
    const int ldb = std::max(m, n);
    size_t l_work = 0;
    status = cusolverDnDDgels_bufferSize(
        handle,
        m, n, nrhs,
        NULL, lda,
        NULL, ldb,
        NULL, ldb,
        NULL, &l_work);
    std::cout <<"Workspace: " << l_work << "!***\n";
    //One if ok
    std::cout << "Find Workspace - 1 if ok: "<<(status == CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS)<<"!***\n";
    double* d_work;
    cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&d_work), l_work);
    int* d_info;
    cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&d_info), sizeof(int));
    cudaMemset(d_info, 0, sizeof(int));
    double* dA, *dB, *dX;
    cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&dA), A.n_elem* sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&dB), B.n_elem* sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(dA,A.memptr(), A.n_elem * sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dB, B.memptr(), B.n_elem * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&dX), refX.n_elem * sizeof(double));
    cudaMemset(dX, 0, refX.n_elem * sizeof(double));
    int iter = 0;
    status = cusolverDnDDgels(handle,
        m, n, nrhs,
        dA, lda,
        dB, ldb,
        dX, ldb,
        d_work, l_work,
        &iter, d_info);
    //One if ok
    std::cout << "Solve status - 1 if ok: " << (status == CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS) << "!***\n";
    int h_info = -1;
    cudaMemcpy(&h_info, d_info,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    std::cout << "Iter: " <<iter << "!\n";
    //0 if ok
    std::cout << "Info - 0 if ok :" << h_info << "!\n";
    //Comparison of the results results
    arma::mat cudaX(refX.n_rows, refX.n_cols);
    cudaMemcpy(cudaX.memptr(), dX, cudaX.n_elem * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    std::cout << "Armadillo result:\n" <<refX.t() <<"\n";
    std::cout << "cusolver result:\n" << cudaX.t() << "\n";

    cudaFree(dA);
    cudaFree(dB);
    cudaFree(dX);
    cudaFree(d_work);
    cudaFree(d_info);
}
```

The results are unfortunately wrong, as only the first column seems ok:

> Workspace: 3653888!***
>
> Find Workspace - 1 if ok: 1!***
>
> Solve status - 1 if ok: 1!***
>
> Iter: -51!
>
> Info - 0 if ok :0!
>
> Armadillo result:
>
> 9.9965  -0.0198   0.0290  -0.0317   0.0027  -0.0197   0.0377  -0.0379  -0.0172   0.0088
>
> 9.9774   0.0485   0.0089  -0.0233   0.0054  -0.0257   0.0130   0.0080   0.0149  -0.0335
>
> cusolver result:
>
> 9.9965  -0.0198   0.0290  -0.0317   0.0027  -0.0197   0.0377  -0.0379  -0.0172   0.0088
>
> -0.8578  0.1884   0.5331  -0.8275   0.1992  -0.0587   1.0014  -0.0250   0.6571  -0.5516

If I run the cuda-memcheck, the first error I get is:

```
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Invalid __global__ write of size 8
=========     at 0x00001aa0 in void copy_AtoB_kernel<double>(int, int, double const *, int, double*, int)
=========     by thread (31,0,0) in block (15,0,0)
=========     Address 0xb00e9b2f8 is out of bounds
=========     Device Frame:void copy_AtoB_kernel<double>(int, int, double const *, int, double*, int) (void copy_AtoB_kernel<double>(int, int, double const *, int, double*, int) : 0x1aa0)
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_8e1b465b962975a0\nvcuda64.dll [0x751f4]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_8e1b465b962975a0\nvcuda64.dll [0x75577]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_8e1b465b962975a0\nvcuda64.dll [0x79cd9]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_8e1b465b962975a0\nvcuda64.dll (cuProfilerStop + 0x11ce4a) [0x32e5ba]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_8e1b465b962975a0\nvcuda64.dll [0x16cfe5]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_8e1b465b962975a0\nvcuda64.dll (cuProfilerStop + 0xf1052) [0x3027c2]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_8e1b465b962975a0\nvcuda64.dll [0x3841d]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_8e1b465b962975a0\nvcuda64.dll [0x3890c]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_8e1b465b962975a0\nvcuda64.dll [0x38be4]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_8e1b465b962975a0\nvcuda64.dll (cuLaunchKernel + 0x234) [0x201044]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\bin\cusolver64_11.dll [0x4856]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\bin\cusolver64_11.dll [0x22b4]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\bin\cusolver64_11.dll (cusolverDnIRSParamsSetTolInner + 0x2269) [0xda299]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\bin\cusolver64_11.dll (cusolverDnIRSParamsSetTolInner + 0x29f1) [0xdaa21]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\bin\cusolver64_11.dll (cusolverDnIRSParamsSetTolInner + 0xea66) [0xe6a96]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\bin\cusolver64_11.dll (cusolverDnZZgesv_bufferSize + 0x5b61) [0x103d41]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\bin\cusolver64_11.dll (cusolverDnIRSXgels + 0x4b6) [0x109cb6]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\bin\cusolver64_11.dll (cusolverDnZZgesv_bufferSize + 0x11e4) [0xff3c4]
=========     Host Frame:C:\sw_source\SEM.Maeve\build\Release\PerformanceTest.exe (main + 0x36c) [0x292d08c]
=========     Host Frame:C:\sw_source\SEM.Maeve\build\Release\PerformanceTest.exe (__scrt_common_main_seh + 0x10c) [0x2ce4378]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL (BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x14) [0x17c24]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll (RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21) [0x6d4d1]
```

So it seems that the code has a memory error, but I cannot detect any error in my usage. Moreover if I comment out the call to cusolverDnDDgels the error disappears.

Any clue of what makes this code failing?

I execute the code on a rtx 2080TI, and the code is compiled with:

```
> nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Sep_15_19:12:04_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.74
Build cuda_11.1.relgpu_drvr455TC455_06.29069683_0
```

in VisualStudio for Windows, using as options:
compute_70,sm_70;compute_75,sm_75;

Comment: iter of `-51` seems to indicate you have reached the iteration maximum, rather than satisfying the convergence condition.  Regarding the `cuda-memcheck` error, I was not able to reproduce that error.  There have been multiple CUDA 11.1 releases, I am using CUDA 11.1 as indicated by `nvcc --version` of 11.1.74 (ie. CUDA 11.1, not CUDA 11.1 update 1).  It may also be a function of the GPU you are using, which you haven't indicated.

Comment: It is weird for such a stupid problem to reach the iteration limits. I added more info on my setup in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my testing, if you:

1. Update to CUDA 11.1 Update 1 (so that `nvcc --version` reports `11.1.105`)
2. Change the `lddx` parameter to be equal to `n`:

   ```
   status = cusolverDnDDgels(handle,
    m, n, nrhs,
    dA, lda,
    dB, ldb,
    dX, n,   //change here and in the buffersize function from ldb to n
    ...
   ```

then I get matching results between cusolver and armadillo.

Comment: I does indeed work for the example above. But if I increase nrhs it returns incorrect results. Probably also nrhs should be part of the the calculation of ldb/ldx.

Comment: Reported on https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/apparent-bug-in-cusolverdnddgels-buffersize/160913